# Is Reflection breaking the encapsulation principle?

Tags: c#, oop, reflection

Okay, let's say we have a class defined like

```
public class TestClass
{
    private string MyPrivateProperty { get; set; }

    // This is for testing purposes
    public string GetMyProperty()
    {
        return MyPrivateProperty;
    }
}
```

then we try:

```
TestClass t = new TestClass { MyPrivateProperty = "test" };
```

Compilation fails with `TestClass.MyPrivateProperty is inaccessible due to its protection level`, as expected.

Try

```
TestClass t = new TestClass();
t.MyPrivateProperty = "test";
```

and compilation fails again, with the same message.

All good until now, we were expecting this.

But then one write:

```
PropertyInfo aProp = t.GetType().GetProperty(
        "MyPrivateProperty",
        BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

// This works:
aProp.SetValue(t, "test", null);

// Check
Console.WriteLine(t.GetMyProperty());
```

and here we are, we managed to change a private field.

Isn't it abnormal to be able to alter some object's internal state just by using reflection?

**Edit:**

Thanks for the replies so far. For those saying "you don't have to use it": what about a class designer, it looks like he can't assume internal state safety anymore?

Comment: Just by using reflection? Someone doesn't just use reflection, the one knows exactly, that he's breaking the API.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Reflection breaks encapsulation principles by giving access to private fields and methods, but it's not the first or only way in which encapsulation can be circumvented; one could argue that serialization exposes all the internal data of a class, information which would normally be private.

It's important to understand that encapsulation is only a technique, one that makes designing behaviour easier, provided consumers agree use an API you have defined. If somebody chooses to circumvent your API using reflection or any other technique, they no longer have the assurance that your object will behave as you designed it. If somebody assigns a value of `null` to a private field, they'd better be ready to catch a `NullReferenceException` the next time they try to use your class!

In my experience, programming is all about assertions and assumptions. The language asserts constraints (classes, interfaces, enumerations) which make creating isolated behaviour much easier to produce, on the assumption that a consumer agrees to not violate those boundaries.

This is a **fair assertion** to make given it makes a divide-and-conquer approach to software development more easy than any technique before it.

Comment: Although this question received other excellent answers, I'm chosing this because of the emphasis put on the fact that one should regard encapsulation as a (recommended) technique among many others.

Answer (score 9):

**Reflection is a tool**. You *may* use it to break encapsulation, when it gives you more than it takes away.

Reflection has a certain "pain" (or cost -- in performance, in readability, in reliability of code) associated with it, so you won't use it for a common problem. It's just *easier* to follow object-oriented principles for common problems, which is one of the goals of the language, commonly referred to as [the pit of success](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000940.html).

On the other hand, there are some tasks that wouldn't be solvable without that mechanism, e.g. working with run-time generate types (though, it is going to be much-much easier starting from .NET 4.0 with it's DLR and the "dynamic" variables in C# 4.0).

Answer (score 4):

You are right that reflection can be opposed to any number of good design principles, but it can also be an essential building block that you can use to support good design principles - e.g. software that can be extended by plugins, inversion of control, etc.

If you're worried that it represents a capability that should be discouraged, you may have a point. But it's not as convenient to use as true language features, so it is easier to do things the right way.

If you think reflection ought to be *impossible*, you're dreaming!

In C++ there is no reflection as such. But there is an underlying "object model" that the compiler-generated machine code uses to access the structure of objects (and virtual functions). So a C++ programmer can break encapsulation in the same way.

```
class RealClass
{
private:
    int m_secret;
};

class FakeClass
{
public:
    int m_notSecret;
};
```

We can take a pointer to an object of type `RealClass` and simply cast it to `FakeClass` and access the "private" member.

Any restricted system has to be implemented on top of a more flexible system, so it is always possible to circumvent it. If reflection wasn't provided as a BCL feature, someone could add it with a library using unsafe code.

In some languages there are ways to encapsulate data so that it is not possible *within the language* to get at the data except in certain prescribed ways. But it will always be possible to cheat if you can find a way to escape out of the language. An extreme example would be scoped variables in JavaScript:

```
(function() {

    var x = 5;

    myGetter = function() { return x; };
    mySetter = function(v) { x = v; };

})();
```

After that executes, the global namespace contains two functions, `myGetter` and `mySetter`, which are the only way to access the value of `x`. Javascript has no reflective ability to get at `x` any other way. But it has to run in some kind of host interpreter (e.g. in the browser), and so there is certainly some horrible way to manipulate `x`. A memory corruption bug in a plugin could do it by accident!

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you could say that. You could also say that the CodeDom, Reflection Emit, and Expression Tree APIs break encapsulation by allowing you to write code on the fly. They are merely facilities provided by .NET. You don't have to use them.

Don't forget that you have to (a) be running in full trust, and (b) explicitly specify `BindingFlags.NonPublic`, in order to access private data. That should be enough of a safety net.

Answer (score 2):

One can say that reflection breaks inheritance and polymorphism as well. When instead of supplying each object type with its own overloaded method version you have a single method that checks object type at run time and switches to a particular behavior for each.

Reflection is a nice tool nevertheless. Sometimes you need to instantiate an object with a private constructor because it's an optimal course of action and you cannot change the class implementation (closed library, can't get in touch with the author any longer). Or you wish to perform some auxiliary operation on a variety of objects in one place. Or maybe you wish to perform logging for certain types. These are the situation when reflection does help without causing any harm.

Answer (score 2):

That's part of the functionality provided by Reflection, but not, I would say, the best use of it.

It only works under Full Trust.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not abnormal.
It is something reflection allows you to do, in some situation what you did might be of some use, in many other that simply will make your code a time bomb.

Reflection is a tool, it can be used or abused.

Regarding the question after your edit: the answer is simply no.
An API designer could do his best, putting a lot of effort into exposing a clean interface and see his API overly misused by using reflection.

An engineer can model a perfect washing machine that is secure, doesn't shock you with electricity and so on, but if you smash it with an hammer until you see the cables no one is going to blame the engineer if you get a shock :D

Comment: Haha, washing machine... So encapsulation comes with a warranty certificate, you're saying ;) ?

Comment: Hehehe... maybe with a contract :P

Answer (score 2):

The encapsulation principle is hold by your API, but reflection gives you a way to work around the API.

Whoever uses reflection knows that he is not using your API correctly!

Answer (score 1):

Reflection can help you to keep your code clean. E.g. when you use hibernate you can directly bind the private variables to DB values and you don't have to write unnecessary setter methods that you would not need otherwise. Seen from this point of view, reflection can help you to keep encapsulation.