# Why does the C# DataMember attribute allow serialization of private fields and properties?

Tags: c#, oop

If you add the `DataMember` attribute to any field or property, including private one's, they will still get serialized. Microsoft notes this explicitly [in their docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute(v=vs.110).aspx):

*"You can apply the DataMemberAttribute to private fields or properties. Be aware that the data returned by the member (even if it's private) will be serialized and deserialized, and thus can be viewed or intercepted by a malicious user or process."*

For example:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [DataMember(Name = "pushed_at")] 
    private string JsonDate { get; set; } //PRIVATE!

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public DateTime PushedAt
    {
        get { return JsonDate; }
    }
}

var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<MyClass>));
var streamTask = client.GetStreamAsync("https://api.mysite.com/hit");
var classes = serializer.ReadObject(await streamTask) as List<MyClass>;

foreach (var myClass in classes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(myClass.JsonDate); //Error because private
    Console.WriteLine(myClass.PushedAt); //Ok and shows serialized data
}
```

Why does this make sense? Isn't the principle of self-encapsulation much more fundamental than serialization? Is the `DataMember` attribute really giving access to a private property outside the class or am I missing something under the hood?

The same thing happens if you make `JsonDate` public and give it a `private` setter.

Comment: `Why does this make sense?` Because it is documented. And it is **opt-in**. So if you don't want it, don't use it. _You can access private members through other means (e.g. reflection) so it isn't a fundamental breach of security._

Comment: @mjwills that's a pretty bad reason. Trying to understand why they decided to allow overriding something as fundamental as private members and properties.

Comment: So you have an object. You want to serialise it. It has private fields. You don't want to make them public. How would you architect that @ministry ?

Comment: Those private members are usually integral to the object's state. If they couldn't be serialized, then you could never truly serialize anything (but objects with only public members) because deserializing them would give you incomplete objects or objects with invalid state - because the private members would have been lost to serialization.

Comment: My point is that saying "it's documented" is not helpful. I'm not a superstar developer with 20 years of experience and I don't know a better way to implement it, that's why I'm asking for a motivation from people smarter than me. Just because I don't have a better way of implementing it doesn't mean there isn't one, or a good reason for the loop hole. I guess you're saying that permitting access to private fields/properties this way is a way to get access that you otherwise cannot while keeping them private to all other users of the class?

Comment: Making something `private` is a lightweight design issue, fundamental to OOP but it is __not a security feature__. So what is the problem?  The older [Serializable] formatters only worked on fields, with an opt-out feature. That was much more of a problem.

Comment: It isn't a loop hole if it is **opt-in**. The developer who uses the attribute has **specifically chosen to allow the behaviour.** In terms of motivation it is relatively obvious - in some cases it is helpful to be able to serialise and de-serialise private state (e.g. the `Count` of a `List<string>`). `I guess you're saying that permitting access to private fields/properties this way is a way to get access that you otherwise cannot while keeping them private to all other users of the class?` Basically yes. You want the data to be `private` generally, but for serialisation you want access.

Comment: So would it be better if you have been forced to make everything you need to serialize public? In your example you would then have two public properties with the same meaning but different return types. I bet that would break some another design principle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Isn't the principle of self-encapsulation much more fundamental than
> serialization?

Serialization happens via reflection so we can change your question:

> Isn't the principle of self-encapsulation much more fundamental than
> reflection?

So [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796055/is-reflection-breaking-the-encapsulation-principle) is the answer

Answer (score 2):

> Isn't the principle of self-encapsulation much more fundamental than serialization?

No. "Pure" programming principles are nice in principle, but sometimes you just have to get things done.

If that includes deserializing into a private member, for whatever reason, the .NET design team apparently decided they're not going to stop you from doing so, even if that would mean there's more clean code out there.

They made this choice deliberately, given it's [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) as you claim.